# Plotting dates given in columns in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I want to plot data on the y axis and dates in the x axis and I have it all in columns. I have data following the format

```
2016.0000000000000  10.000000000000000  14.000000000000000  117.62999700000000     
2016.0000000000000  10.000000000000000  13.000000000000000  116.98000300000000     
2016.0000000000000  10.000000000000000  12.000000000000000  117.33999600000000     
2016.0000000000000  10.000000000000000  11.000000000000000  116.30000300000000     
2016.0000000000000  10.000000000000000  10.000000000000000  116.05000300000000     
2016.0000000000000  10.000000000000000  7.0000000000000000  114.05999799999999     
2016.0000000000000  10.000000000000000  6.0000000000000000  113.88999900000000
```

in a file, where the structure is year, month, day, data, with tabs as separators. The code I've tried running is:

```
set xdata time
set timefmt "\"%Y\t%m\t%d\""
set xrange ['"2016\t10\t14"':'"2006\t10\t16"']

plot "data.txt" u 1:2
```

but apparently this isn't taking the dates as `x` values and the data as `y` values, since this error message comes out when running:

```
line 5: warning: Skipping data file with no valid points
line 5: Can't plot with an empty x range!
```

Line 5 referring to the line including the plot command. How can I tell the program that what I want to plot is the data versus the dates?

Answer (score 0):

```
set xdata time
set timefmt "%Y %m %d"
set xrange ["2016 10 06":"2006 10 16"]

plot "data.txt" u (sprintf("%d %d %d",$1,$2,$3)):4
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: It's not working, an error comes up saying "all points y value undefined!"